# Django POST request is empty

Tags: python, django, post, request

Running Django 4.1.1. Having this code below in template. By clicking a button it sends a data to delete apropriate marker.

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ol>
        {% for marker in markers %}
            <li>
                {{ marker }} - <button class="button btn-primary" id="delete" value="{{ marker.pk }}" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
</form>
```

In views.py

```
def user_markers(request):
    markers = Marker.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).select_related()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get("delete"))  # gives me None
        marker = Marker.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("delete"))
        marker.delete()
    context = {
        "markers": markers,
    }
    return render(request, "hub/markers.html", context)
```

The problem is that request.POST.get("delete") is empty.
POST data has only 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify this as name, so:

```
<button class="button btn-primary" id="delete" name="delete" value="{{ marker.pk }}" type="submit">Delete</button>
```

If you do not specify a name, it will not be include in the POST data, and thus it will not contain any value that is passed with the button.

You might want to improve the view function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect


@login_required
def user_markers(request):
    markers = Marker.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).select_related()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_object_or_404(
            Marker, owner=request.user, pk=request.POST.get('delete')
        ).delete()
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')  # need to redirect
    context = {
        'markers': markers,
    }
    return render(request, 'hub/markers.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.